# No Badge Progress color for Golden Badges?

Tags: discussion, design, badge-progress

**Update #2:** Seems that **it was my secondary screen the one that didn't show the color!** Tried with another screen and I could see the progress clearer... perhaps a *stronger color will make it easier to see across different devices?*

<s>**Update:** *Seems to be an issue in Firefox, as I tried on Chrome and the progress is visible.*</s>

---

I just noticed that the badge progress on your user profile had it's style changed (don't know when but it seems that recently).

However, seems that the *progress of gold badges is not working properly*. If we see the Bronze and Silver badges, they are "filled with color" as you progress on the badge, however golden ones are not colored (just the border).

Here a picture illustrating what I say:

[image]

**Is there a reason for this behavior?**

Comment: The bar in your picture is colored for progress, it's just a lot lighter than the other ones.

Comment: Damn, I need a pair of eyeglasses then :(

Comment: I just noticed that, when opening that picture to edit (on Shutter) the golden color appears, but outside the editor, or when seeing the gold progress from other places It's hardly visible (I don't even see It to be honest). Was there a recent change @animuson ?

Comment: Huh, I viewed the progress now from Chrome and the color is there! However, I can't see it on Firefox... updating the post

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I can see the colouring in the picture attached to the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm also on FF and can't see it :/ will see if it has something to do with my screen colour

Comment: ...aaaand it seems it was my second screen the one that didn't show the color, the one attatched to my laptop does show the color a bit stronger than my external screen... I feel a bit dumb now :/ could this suggest a stronger color may be a good idea so it's visible across different devices?

Comment: That coloring is way too light.  Depending on what angle I view it (top of screen or bottom of screen) the coloring is lighter when looked at on the lower part of the screen (so I'm viewing the pixels from above).  It also gets stronger when I view it from the side.  With the differences in screens, brightness, contrast, ambient lighting, viewing angle, etc. when this is looked at, a more prominent (darker) shade of yellow would be easier to see.